# Multiple `setState` not synchronized - if one uses a value obtained from `await`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I found that, if:

1. there are two `setState`
2. the first one is called with a value obtained from `await`
3. the both are called in the same thread

then, there is a frame where one state is set but the other is not.

Example:

```
const [bool1, setBool1] = useState(false)
const [bool2, setBool2] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const _bool1 = await true
    setBool1(_bool1)
    const _bool2 = true
    setBool2(_bool2)
  })()
}, [])

console.log(`bool1: ${bool1}, bool2: ${bool2}`)
```

Live example (open browser console for output):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
  const {useState, useEffect} = React;
  const App = () => {
    const [bool1, setBool1] = useState(false)
    const [bool2, setBool2] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        const _bool1 = await true;
        setBool1(_bool1);
        const _bool2 = true;
        setBool2(_bool2);
      })();
    }, [])

    console.log(`bool1: ${bool1}, bool2: ${bool2}`);
    return <p>See browser console for output</p>;
  }
  
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
</script>
```

The output is:

```
bool1: false, bool2: false
bool1: true, bool2: false
bool1: true, bool2: true
```

Here, the second line is confusing - I feel that there shouldn't be a frame where `bool1` and `bool2` don't have the same value. I know the fact that `setState` doesn't set a value in the same frame in general, but is that fact actually related in this case?

More confusingly, if 1. is not met, namely, if I remove `await` for `setBool1`, the second line vanishes. I don't get how the `await` breaks the synchronization between `setBool1` and `setBool2` in this case - because I think the promise is already reasolved when `setBool1` is called, so it shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `useState` hook triggers re-render. So, since it's not batched due to asynchronous state updates, when `setBool1(_bool1)` is executed the component re-renders with the new `bool1` value and then continues with the next `setBool2(_bool2)` that is why you see this happening in that order:

```
bool1: false, bool2: false
bool1: true, bool2: false
bool1: true, bool2: true
```

### What's Batching?

> A React feature that combines all the state updates into a
> single update, causing a single re-render thereby improving the
> performance of the app. In earlier versions of React, batching was
> only done for the event handlers.

## But!

> In the case of asynchronous state updates, ***state updates are not batched***.

Here you can find a good and extensive explanation https://blog.saeloun.com/2021/07/22/react-automatic-batching.html

More info: https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21

**This is supposed to change with React 18**

> Starting in React 18 with createRoot, all updates will be
> automatically batched, no matter where they originate from.